# Postfix on Ubuntu not delivering mail to a few addresses

Tags: email, postfix

On my ubuntu server my WordPress installation sends email the normal way using wp_mail (which in turn uses php mail()..).

The server is set up with Postfix for delivery.

Recently there's been a problem with some addresses not receiving emails sent from the server.

Let's say the server itself uses domain `server.com` which is also used for Google apps email. The domain has the appropriate SPF record set.

Emails sent to `<my-username>@server.com`, `<my-username>@hotmail.com` and `<my-username>@gmail.com` are all delivered fine.

However emails sent to `<my-username>@<my-own-google-app-domain>.com` are not delivered. They don't even hit the spam folder.

Here is a mail log which I think might be relevant (email addresses replaced to correspond with above):

```
Sep  3 10:39:00 vps postfix/pickup[20267]: B991F2A11: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Sep  3 10:39:00 vps postfix/cleanup[20354]: B991F2A11: message-id=<a28beaca77daed562dcbdc1409fff9fc@www.server.com>
Sep  3 10:39:00 vps postfix/qmgr[20268]: B991F2A11: from=<www-data@server.com>, size=730, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  3 10:39:01 vps postfix/smtp[20356]: B991F2A11: to=<<my-username@<my-custom-ga-domain>.com>, relay=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[2a00:1450:400c:c0a::1b]:25, delay=0.4, delays=0.05/0.01/0.05/0.28, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1441269756 li14si9718740wic.1 - gsmtp)
Sep  3 10:39:01 vps postfix/qmgr[20268]: B991F2A11: removed
Sep  3 10:40:01 vps postfix/pickup[20267]: DFD2E2A39: uid=105 from=<smmsp>
Sep  3 10:40:01 vps postfix/cleanup[20354]: DFD2E2A39: message-id=<20150903084001.DFD2E2A39@vps.server.com>
Sep  3 10:40:01 vps postfix/qmgr[20268]: DFD2E2A39: from=<smmsp@server.com>, size=708, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  3 10:40:02 vps postfix/smtp[20356]: DFD2E2A39: to=<root@server.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.166.27]:25, delay=0.21, delays=0.03/0/0.03/0.15, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.166.27] said: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 w4si45121598wju.16 - gsmtp (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Sep  3 10:40:02 vps postfix/cleanup[20354]: 1DABA2A37: message-id=<20150903084002.1DABA2A37@vps.server.com>
Sep  3 10:40:02 vps postfix/bounce[20389]: DFD2E2A39: sender non-delivery notification: 1DABA2A37
Sep  3 10:40:02 vps postfix/qmgr[20268]: 1DABA2A37: from=<>, size=3181, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  3 10:40:02 vps postfix/qmgr[20268]: DFD2E2A39: removed
Sep  3 10:40:02 vps postfix/smtp[20356]: 1DABA2A37: to=<smmsp@server.com>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c0a::1b]:25, delay=0.29, delays=0/0/0.16/0.13, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host aspmx.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c0a::1b] said: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 d4si33273494wjn.153 - gsmtp (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Sep  3 10:40:02 vps postfix/qmgr[20268]: 1DABA2A37: removed
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

**Edit:**

Here is the output of `postconf | grep '^mydomain\|^myhostname'`:

```
mydomain = server.com
myhostname = vps.server.com
mydestination = vps.server.com, localhost.server.com, localhost
```

(where server.com is actually my server's domain name)

**Edit2:**

Mails sent from the server under postfix seem to have the wrong time: e.g.

`Date: Thu, 3 Sep 2015 13:45:16 +0000`

This is 1 hour out from what it should be, even though the timezone should be "Europe/London", currently on BST.

The server date is correct, just postfix (both mail headers and log entries) are incorrect.

I'm thinking this may be making some emails marked as spam

Comment: question updated!

Comment: Actually, `mydestination` is probably more important: `postconf  | grep '^mydomain\|^myhostname\|^mydestination'`

Comment: that's added...

Comment: The Postfix configuration settings look like they're OK. I presume that since the remnants of sendmail have been removed, your mail log files don't have those error messages any more. Aside from that, I'm out of any other ideas.

Comment: yeh, I think it must be the time, as mail get successfully delivered to some addresses. Could be a spam thing but I'm not sure how to fix the time

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of being too obvious, it seems that the (Google) mail server for “server.com” doesn’t recognise `root@server.com` or `smmsp@server.com` as
valid recipients.

> The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 w4si45121598wju.16 - gsmtp (in reply to RCPT TO command))

### smmsp

After looking at the log files more closely, I notice that *after* the first mail has been sent from `wwww-data` to `<my-username@<my-custom-ga-domain>.com>`, there’s a message being sent from `smmsp` to `root`. This attempt to send fails and the third mail message being logged is the resulting attempt to send a DSN back to `<smmsp@server.com>`.

After searching the web, I came across this link, [Postfix/Sendmail: Frequent emails from smmsp to root](http://languor.us/postfix-sendmail-frequent-emails-smmsp-root) which states that smmsp is *Sendmail Message Submission Program*. This post suggests that sendmail may not be completely removed from the system. For their Debian-based system, the poster verified this by running `dpkg -l | grep send` and then removing the sendmail packages using:

```
aptitude remove sendmail-bin sendmail-cf sendmail-doc
```

If sendmail programs are installed on your system, it would be best to remove them (as they would conflict with Postfix) and then re-try your mail-sending test.

### Destination domains

Another issue that could be affecting you is that the Postfix on your virtual server sees a mail that should be delivered to `<address@server.com>` so it thinks such mails should be delivered locally.

You’ve configured `mydomain` to be `server.com` and if not set otherwise,
Postfix uses `$myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost` as its default
setting for `mydestination` the domains that it delivers for.

Edit: Having seen the updated Postfix configuration settings, this doesn’t seem to be the issue here.

Comment: But why is postfix trying to send to `root` and `smmsp`? This log message is raised when php mail sends to `<my-username>@<my-own-google-app-domain>.com`

Comment: The mx records for `server.com` are just the standard google apps ones as found on https://support.google.com/a/answer/33915?hl=en

Comment: @harryg Cool. Just thought I'd check that piece of information. Any luck in checking for Sendmail?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've removed any remnants of sendmail but I've noticed the time is wrong in the mail headers - out by 1 hour - even though the server's time is correct. This may be getting the mail classed as spam. Trying to fix this but not sure how to solve with postfix or why it's not just using the server time for sent time.